# Managing PDF usage rights in iText7

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm using `PdfReader.HasUsageRights()` and `PdfReader.RemoveUsageRights()` in iTextSharp v5. Can't seem to find similar functionality in iText7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no direct alternative but it's easy to implement those methods yourself:

```
public boolean hasUsageRights(PdfDocument pdfDocument) {
    PdfDictionary perms = pdfDocument.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Perms);
    if (perms == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return perms.containsKey(new PdfName("UR")) || perms.containsKey(PdfName.UR3);
}

public void removeUsageRights(PdfDocument pdfDocument) {
    PdfDictionary perms = pdfDocument.getCatalog().getPdfObject().getAsDictionary(PdfName.Perms);
    if (perms == null) {
        return;
    }
    perms.remove(new PdfName("UR"));
    perms.remove(PdfName.UR3);
    if (perms.size() == 0) {
        pdfDocument.getCatalog().remove(PdfName.Perms);
    }
}
```

If you need the first method then you can pass either a document created with `PdfDocument(PdfReader, PdfWriter)` constructor or with `PdfDocument(PdfReader)` one. If you need the second method then you need to pass a document created in stamping mode, i.e. with `PdfDocument(PdfReader, PdfWriter)` constructor

Comment: Thanks Alexey. That's exactly what I've done for now, which is pretty much copy-paste from the v5 source. I thought maybe there was smth in v7 I'd missed...